# Datagrid - How to change the first 3 lines backgroundcolor

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, colors

I have a datagrid, that has as its base an XML file.
Depending on the data in the xml, the list gets sorted.

What i now want to do is change the first 3 lines background color, for example the first one red, second yellow and 3rd blue.
after the 3rd it can all be just default white.

I cant find how to do this, anyone could help me out ?

thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most simplest way would be to handle the `LoadingRow` event of `DataGrid` and update the colors inside it.

```
private void dg_LoadingRow(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    int index = e.Row.GetIndex();
    if (index == 0)
        e.Row.Background = Brushes.Blue;
     else if (index == 1)
        e.Row.Background = Brushes.Red;
     else if (index == 2)
        e.Row.Background = Brushes.White;
}
```

another way could be to retrieve the first three `DataGridRow` from `DataGrid` using the method described in [this](http://techiethings.blogspot.com/2010/05/get-wpf-datagrid-row-and-cell.html) post. Then use the dataGridRow's `Background` property to change it's color

A more cleaner way would be to define a `style` for `DataGridRow` and use `triggers` to change the `background` color of particular `DataGridRow`. I am not sure if you have some criteria behind changing `background` color of first three rows or it is a hard coded requirement. If it is some criteria or value in `DataGrid` then you should go for `Style` based approach.